# Was API hooking done as needed for Stuxnet to work? I don't think so

Tags: windows, api, character-encoding, file-handling

Caveat: I am a political science student and I have tried my level best to understand the technicalities; if I still sound naive please overlook that.

In the [Symantec report on Stuxnet](http://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/media/security_response/whitepapers/w32_stuxnet_dossier.pdf), the authors say that once the worm infects the 32-bit Windows computer which has a WINCC setup on it, Stuxnet does many things and that it specifically hooks the function `CreateFileA()`. This function is the route which the worm uses to actually infect the .s7p project files that are used to program the PLCs. ie when the PLC programmer opens a file with .s7p the control transfers to the hooked function `CreateFileA_hook()` instead of `CreateFileA()`. Once Stuxnet gains the control it covertly inserts code blocks into the PLC without the programmers knowledge and hides it from his view.

However, it should be noted that there is also one more function called `CreateFileW()` which does the same task as `CreateFileA()` but both work on different character sets. `CreateFileA` works with ASCII character set and `CreateFileW` works with wide characters or Unicode character set. Farsi (the language of the Iranians) is a language that needs unicode character set and not ASCII Characters. *I'm assuming that the developers of any famous commercial software (for ex. WinCC) that will be sold in many countries will take 'Localization' and/or 'Internationalization' into consideration while it is being developed in order to make the product fail-safe* ie. the software developers would use `UNICODE` while compiling their code and not just 'ASCII'. Thus, I think that `CreateFileW()` would have been invoked on a WINCC system in Iran instead of `CreateFileA()`. Do you agree?

My question is: If Stuxnet has hooked only the function `CreateFileA()` then based on the above assumption there is a significant chance that it did not work at all? I think my doubt will get clarified if: my assumption is proved wrong, or the Symantec report is proved incorrect. Please help me clarify this doubt.

Edit: For more clarity of my question and what I'm looking for.

Is it possible that the WinCC STL Editor be programmed in the following way?

```
//Pseudocode Begins
if (locale == ASCII Dependent) //like US, UK, Australia etc.
{
     CreateFileA(); //with appropriate parameters
}
else if (locale == UNICODE Dependent) //like Middle East, China, Japan etc
{
     CreateFileW(); //with appropriate parameters
} //Pseudocode ends
```

If it is possible then does it follows that Stuxnet would work appropriately in the US but not in China or Japan or Iran?

Comment: *there is a significant chance that it did not work at all?* I think there's ample evidence that it **did** in fact work. For one thing, if it hadn't worked, it's unlikely that anybody would have ever noticed it. Or are you suggesting that Symantec's analysis is wrong and there was some other mechanism involved?

Comment: @Caleb People say Stuxnet worked on the basis of 'correlation'. The timeline of the dip in the no. of centrifuges was correlated with Stuxnet's timeline. No one has ever proved/disproved the 'causality'. It is difficult to establish causality between Stuxnet and the dip in the no. of centrifuges based only on open-source data. I'm just questioning everything to either prove or disprove causality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many technical works are carried out all in English- it is the lingua franca of programming. It is not particularly uncommon at all for foreign teams to work, code, and document exclusively in English. For example, look at the Lua project, written by a bunch of Brazilians. Documentation? English only. Filenames? All English. And the PLC code would not support Unicode either, so it's not like the Iranians had the option to work all in Arabic.

It does surprise me that it didn't hook CreateFileW, but I suppose that it knew in advance that WinCC only uses CreateFileA.

Comment: I'm not sure about your statement "The PLC code would not support Unicode either." I dug into the Siemens Automation Chat Forum for the details about programming using WinCC and found this document. http://cache.automation.siemens.com/dnl/Dk2NTYzAAAA_27251400_DL/Product_Information_STEP7_V54_SP31_Japanese.pdf On the second page it says "1. You can only edit projects which were created with the English or Japanese character set.
2. Please note that you use the single byte format when entering addresses" and other important points. Does that convince you about my doubt? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Although I must say that there is no 'Persian' or 'Farsi' service pack available for WinCC. But I don't know how much it would impact my original question.

Comment: @TheKaykay: No, it proves my assertion that all the code would be in English. Obviously WinCC does not support coding in Arabic, and the developers would have had to give their files Latin-alphabet names, so WinCC could use CreateFileA to create them.

Comment: Nice. Yes obviously they can't code in Arabic or Farsi. But WinCC has the ability to deal with Unicode filenames right? Since files can be coded in Japanese they can be named in Japanese as well. It suggests me that internally WinCC was in some way programmed to call `CreateFileW()` and not just `CreateFileA()` If that is the case then either the developers knew exactly what they wanted or they 'overlooked' aspects of localisation and internationalisation?

Comment: @TheKaykay: Most likely, they just set the OEM character page to Japanese to support that language.

Comment: I see. I had not considered this possibility. Anyway, is there any way I could clear all my doubts? I'm thinking of buying the WinCC software and installing it on my system and then running Dependency Walker on the DLL that is replaced by Stuxnet. That is the DLL where it hooks `CreateFileA`. I should check if the original DLL invokes `CreateFileA` or `CreateFileW`. But still I can't be sure because the WinCC that I buy may not be the same as the one used in Iran. Does this generate 'reasonable doubt' in your mind that Stuxnet might not have worked or Symantec report is not accurate??

Comment: @TheKayKay: Nope, not at all. Those guys almost certainly knew the exact WinCC, Windows, etc versions in use, had a copy, and reverse-engineered it significantly- for example, you can write or download a trivial tool to see what Windows functions a given executable uses. They most certainly tested it before use. Many hacks and other things work this way. It does not surprise me or introduce doubt at all that in a totally ideal world, something different should have been hooked, given that we know in advance that it was not ideal in exactly this respect.

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression that the WinCC software would call CreateFileA/W based on the locale and not just UNICODE was used while compiling it or not. However, like you said it still surprises me that they only hooked CreateFileA :-) Now that many of you have cleared my doubts I think that my assumption was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @TheKaykay: No, which version of CreateFile is called is fixed at compile time. If the executable isn't compiled for unicode, it will call CreateFileA, no matter what locale it's running on. (You could in theory write code that calls CreateFileA/W under different circumstances, but why would you - unicode supersedes ASCII, so once you have a unicode program, there's no reason to keep the old ASCII code, too.)

Comment: @nikie Agreed why would someone invoke CreateFileA when Unicode supersedes ASCII. What is the possible explanation then for WinCC's ability to work with file content and file names in Japanese? Look above, in my first reply to DeadMG I've pasted a link which shows that WinCC is able to work with projects in Japanese. How would CreateFileA react to a filename written in Japanese?

Comment: @TheKaykay: If the character page is set correctly, then "just fine".

Comment: @DeadMG Just to ensure I've understood you correctly. Are you saying that if character encoding page is set correctly then if `filename = 付いた添付ファイル` (for example) `CreateFileA(filename, ...)` would work without any problems? I think this is where I differ or am unclear, clearing this point can possibly put an end to this discussion. :-)

Comment: @Thekaykay: Yes. That is how internationalization worked prior to Unicode. The reason Unicode came about is because it doesn't work between machines with different code pages, for example, and is a big headache for any kind of serialization.

Comment: @DeadMG Well, it clears my doubt perfectly. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `CreateFileA` and `CreateFileW` differ only in the character set of *the filename itself*. The actual contents of the file are just bytes in both cases, and free to be interpreted by the program in whatever way it likes.

In fact, in all modern Windows, the `*A` functions are typically just very thin wrappers around the `*W` functions where all they do is convert the arguments to/from Unicode.

Comment: Yes absolutely it would be dependent on the filename and not the content of the file. And, `CreateFileA()` internally calls `CreateFileW()` Be the filename in Unicode or not `CreateFileW()` would be called anyway. But `CreateFileA()` would be called is not necessarily true right? But it would all depend on `UNICODE`was used in compiling WinCC or not. Is there any possibility that 'locale' configuration would affect which of the two functions will be called by WinCC? Can WinCC be configured in a way to call `CreateFileA()` in the US and `CreateFileW()` in Japan or the Middle East?

Comment: Technically it's possible to choose between calling `CreateFileW` and `CreateFileA` at runtime, but in practise it never happens. It's far too complicated and since one is just written in terms of the other, there's just no benefit (i.e. if you ever "need" the `CreateFileW` version, it's easier to just call `CreateFileW` in all situations). In most situations, the `*A` versions are almost always used by applications that were originally written before Windows 2000/XP became the dominant versions of Windows (it's harder to convert from `*A` to `*W` than to use `*W` from the start).

Comment: Okay. But we don't know when was WinCC's STL Editor written. So anything is possible. They might have written using only *A versions or they might have used *W versions too. But since by default WinCC supports five languages English, German, Spanish, French and Italian and also has WinCC Asian version for Japanese, Chinese and Korean, can we say that WinCC uses only *A versions of APIs?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm assuming that the developers of any famous commercial software (for ex. WinCC) that will be sold in many countries will take 'Localization' and/or 'Internationalization' into consideration while it is being developed in order to make the product fail-safe ie. the software developers would use UNICODE while compiling their code and not just 'ASCII'. Thus, I think that CreateFileW() would have been invoked on a WINCC system in Iran instead of CreateFileA(). Do you agree?

Today, yes. But WinCC was first introduced in 1995. Back then, Unicode was still quite new and it wasn't common that programs supported unicode. Among other reasons, so they would be run on Windows 95/98/ME, which never supported unicode.

Instead, people used [codepages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) to display non-latin characters: Simply put, you'd tell the OS that your process was using [codepage 1256](http://www.science.co.il/language/Character-Code.asp?s=1256) now and the operating system would display characters in the 128..255 range as farsi characters (if you have the right fonts).

> My question is: If Stuxnet has hooked only the function CreateFileA() then based on the above assumption there is a significant chance that it did not work at all?

Whoever created Stuxnet didn't just write a worm that would hook into `CreateFileA` and hope WinCC would call `CreateFileA` eventually. I'm sure they had a copy of exactly the version of WinCC they were targeting. They probably debugged it to find out which function to hook into. If WinCC would have been built using unicode, they'd have hooked into `CreateFileW` instead.

Comment: thank you great answer. Stuxnet looks specifically for WinCC Step 7 version. I checked on the Siemens website and found WinCC S7 SP3 was released in Dec2011, SP2 was released in Sep 2010 . Stuxnet was estimated to have been developed in 2008 by computer experts. I can safely say that the WinCC in operation in Iran is not the one made in 1995? So either WinCC only works with `CreateFileA` in all the locations or they use some method to invoke `CreateFileW` whenever needed? Would you agree?

Comment: Secondly, perhaps you can be sure that the developers had exact version of WinCC they were targeting. But can you say with the same conviction that Symantec used that exact version in their test-setup they created in their Culver City office? I don't think you can say that with absolute conviction. :-) perhaps I'm wrong...

Comment: @TheKaykay: You have a wrong impression of how software development works. They don't rewrite WinCC from scratch for every new version. They started development in the 90's, and at that time, it was common to write non-unicode software- So they wrote non-unicode software. And that kind of software doesn't get magically unicode-aware just by adding new features or putting a new version label on it.

Comment: Yeah but they do try to do away with the deprecated practices of software development in their newer versions of software. 95 to 2008 is 13 years. They are releasing the service pack in about a years time, as mentioned above. If they keep all the legacy stuff without phasing out then I think they are too incompetent.

Comment: You are looking at industrial software, which tends to get written once against certain hardware and not fixed. And you are looking at a 3rd world country which has older hardware and older OS versions. I would be more surprised if they were running on Win7x64 than if they were running on 98SE.

Comment: @WyattBarnett I'm looking at the STL Step 7 Editor which is used to program PLCs which gets shipped as part of the entire WinCC package. I doubt a PLC program editor will be written specific to one industrial system.

Comment: @TheKaykay: *"Yeah but they do try to do away with the deprecated practices of software development in their newer versions of software"*. If that was so, then Stuxnet wouldn't work, would it. Obviously they never switched to unicode. And, honestly, I don't see much reason why they should. They have a tested codebase that does what it's supposed to do on the systems where it's installed. Nobody would break that without a clear business reason just because you think it's "deprecated practice".

Comment: @nikie :-) I guess we both have different entities in mind when we refer to WinCC. I'm referring to WinCC's Step 7 STL Editor an editor used to program PLCs which Stuxnet infects. The major business logic of the entire WinCC as a whole would have had gone very few or no changes, of course, I agree with that. But a PLC program editor will definitely have under gone changes from 95 to 2008. Do you agree? They will have made it compatible with Unicode.

Comment: @TheKaykay: Again, if they *had* built it unicode-aware, hooking into CreateFileA wouldn't have worked. You know that. I get the impression you don't want to discuss software development, but instead want someone to confirm your theory that Stuxnet could never have worked. But you *know* it did work.

Comment: @nikie Maybe I am arguing too hard like a lawyer here; Sorry for that. But the only reason for my strong scepticism is that Stuxnet plays safe in all the cases where it hooks-on to functions by hooking-on to Unicode-related functions only. For example, `LoadLibraryW` `FindFirstFileW` `FindNextFileW` `FindFirstFileExW` and many others. But it stands out in the case of `CreateFileA` Why? Why hook-on to all Unicode functions and hook to `CreateFileA` when it also internally calls `CreateFileW`? And I neither believe Stuxnet worked nor deny it. I'm just being the devil's advocate here.

Comment: @nikie It is believed that two teams probably developed Stuxnet. One developed the part which infects systems and propagates to different systems. Second is the part which infects WinCC and the PLCs. The first team seems to know malware development well but the second team seems to know PLC programming well and they also seem to know gas centrifuges too well. The first team hooked-on to only Unicode related functions but the second did not. Why? I don't know the answer. There are many more inconsistencies that I have found and it is difficult for me to put it all here in these small comments.

Comment: @nikie anyway guess I went off the topic in the above comment. Thanks for the answers and the discussion really really helpful. I think I'll just buy the WinCC software and find the particular DLL that Stuxnet hooks and then run it through dependency walker to see it for myself What APIs does it call. Only `CreateFileA` or are/is there any other call to `CreateFileW`. Hope I did not waste time of you people here. Sorry if I did that.